# CSS - Transitions for numerous auto size containers

Tags: html, css

I'm currently writing some code for a webpage which displays generated content. The main container, named with the class `block`, holds another container, respectively named `container`. Inside of the container, there are multiple elements, named as `object`.

Both containers have a `height: auto;` CSS setting, as the height depends upon the content inside. The visual effects of this site are something that I am extremely passionate about getting spot on, and I'm wanting to use a transition effect to enable the containers to change height smoothly, rather than instantaneously as it does normally.

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/934zc2b9/1/) for a code/visual perspective.

Click on the button labelled with 'Add new object' to view the effect that is default. How would I enable a smooth height change of both containers?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS cannot animate to or from `auto` values. What you'll need to do is use JavaScript to set the initial `height` of the `.block` element and then update it as you add each `.object` element. Here's an example (apologies for the roughness of it, was a bit pressed for time. It should point you in the right direction, at least):

```js
var span=document.createElement("span"),
 block=document.querySelector(".block"),
 container=document.querySelector(".container");
span.classList.add("object");
block.style.height=container.offsetHeight+"px";
document.querySelector("body>span").addEventListener("click",function(){
    container.appendChild(span.cloneNode(0));
    block.style.height=container.offsetHeight+"px";
},0);
```

```css
span {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.block {
  position: absolute;
  width: 360px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.1);
  left: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  transition:height .25s;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: auto;
  min-height: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.15);
  font-size: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}
.object {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f0f;
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
  <div class='container'>
    <span class='object'></span>
  </div>
</div>
<span>Add new object</span>
```

Comment: I feared that JS would be the answer. Thanks for your help! Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome :) If you're already using JS to add the `.object` elements, it's not that big a deal to use it to set the `height` as well.